# How to interpret the result of using timeit?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, timeit

when I run the following code in Jupyter Notebook

```
%%timeit -n5
ls = [i for i in range(10)]
n = ls[::-1]
```

It gives an output `789 ns ± 88.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 5 loops each)`. Previously I thought `... of 7 runs ...` means the results of the best 7 runs, but as you can see here I only have 5 loops, so what does this 7 mean?

Comment: `-n` indicates how may times to run the code per run. The default repeat count `-r` is 5. I guess it was overridden?

Comment: @JeffMercado I think the default -r is 7 for my interpreter since it shows the best 7 runs every time if no value is assigned to ```-r```. I'm just curious why would it still take the best 7 runs when there are less than 7 runs in total